# React How to merge an array and an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this two states:

```
stateOne: [
  'marca01',
  'marca02'
]

stateTwo: [
 {
   PRODUCTO:'hat',
   PRICE:1499,
   CATEGORY:'Men'
 },
 {
   PRODUCTO:'Shirt',
   PRICE:1233,
   CATEGORY:'Woman'
 }
]
```

And I'm using lodash to merge both in a third state, but as you see the first state is an array and the second one is an array of objects so I can't merge these two like I want to...

Something like this:

```
stateThree: [
 {
   PRODUCTO:'hat',
   PRICE:1499,
   CATEGORY:'Men',
   MARK:'marca01'
 },
 {
   PRODUCTO:'Shirt',
   PRICE:1233,
   CATEGORY:'Woman',
   MARK:'marca02'
 }
]
```

How can I get the desired result (is not necessary to use lodash)

Comment: What lodash code are you using? That's likely a huge hint.

Comment: `stateTwo.forEach((s,i) => s.MARK = stateOne[i]);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React merge states with same objects values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53419751/react-merge-states-with-same-objects-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without lodash :

```
const state3 = state2.map((product, index) => ({
    ...product,
    MARK: state1[index]
}));
```

Here `.map` returns a new array whose new values are returned by the anonymous function.

The spread operator `...product` flattens the previous object properties in the new object. This syntaxic sugar can be replaced by `Object.assign`.

Then we add a new MARK property based on the other state with the same index.

I used the map method and the spread operator in order to prevent state mutation which can be harmful in React.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the second array, and add the properties.

```js
let s1 = [
  'marca01',
  'marca02'
]
let s2 = [
 {
   PRODUCTO:'hat',
   PRICE:1499,
   CATEGORY:'Men'
 },
 {
   PRODUCTO:'Shirt',
   PRICE:1233,
   CATEGORY:'Woman'
 }]

s2.forEach((x,i) => x.MARK = s1[i])
console.log(s2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
stateThree = stateTwo.map( (element, i) => ({...element, MARK: stateOne[i] } ))
```